# flutter audioplayer error when playing audio

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

im triyng to play a sound on a button click using the package audio player 0.18.0, but every time i press the button to make the sound play i get this error.

> E/flutter ( 4036): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
> E/flutter ( 4036): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
> E/flutter ( 4036): 
> E/flutter ( 4036): #1      getTemporaryDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:55:24)
> E/flutter ( 4036): 
> E/flutter ( 4036): #2      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:79:27)
> E/flutter ( 4036): 
> E/flutter ( 4036): #3      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:97:31)
> E/flutter ( 4036): 
> E/flutter ( 4036): #4      AudioCache.getAbsoluteUrl (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:192:17)
> E/flutter ( 4036): 
> E/flutter ( 4036): #5      AudioCache.play (package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart:122:18)
> E/flutter ( 4036):

what do i do to fix this?

Comment: Are you on the latest version of the package?

Comment: no, the latest version of the package has its own error upon running it, something to do with getter name. only when i used older versions was i able to run it but always came to this error

Answer (score 0):

I got this error and I did the same thing but I found the solution :

You need to use

```yaml
audioplayers:^1.0.1
```

then if you want to play an asset audio
just type:

```dart
final audio2= AudioPlayer();
audio2.play(AssetSource('Your wav file or your mp3 file '));
```

and thats it and it will work perfectly:).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the recent update of the package, the solution is: use audioplayers as package & AudioPlayer() as constructor & this method play(AssetSource('')) .